# Kentico 9 Continuous Integration Error

Tags: kentico

I'm working on the Kentico E-commerce project, it was moved from 8.2.48 version to 9.0.50 for the purpose of using Continuous Integration feature, but there is an error now:

```
Message: Serialization of object type @Product tax class@ (ECommerce.SKUTaxClass) failed for object @551, 2@ ([Unknown]: 0). See inner exception for further details.

    Exception type: CMS.ContinuousIntegration.ObjectTypeSerializationException
    Stack Trace: 
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreSingleObjectTypeObject(FileSystemStoreJob storeJob, ObjectTypeInfo typeInfo, String objectType, BaseInfo info, Int32 counter, Int32 total)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.@@c__DisplayClass6.@StoreAllObjectTypeObjects@b__3(BaseInfo info)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemJob.CancellableForEach[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`2 action)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemJob.CancellableForEach[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`1 action)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreAllObjectTypeObjects(String objectType, Int32 counter, Int32 total)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemJob.CancellableForEach[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`2 action)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreObjects()
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.RunInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemAllJob.Run(Nullable`1 cancellationToken)

    Message: Serialization of the object CMS.Ecommerce.SKUTaxClassInfo (ecommerce.skutaxclass) has failed.

    Exception type: CMS.ContinuousIntegration.ObjectSerializationException
    Stack Trace: 
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractSingleObjectJob.Run(BaseInfo baseInfo)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreSingleObjectTypeObject(FileSystemStoreJob storeJob, ObjectTypeInfo typeInfo, String objectType, BaseInfo info, Int32 counter, Int32 total)

    Message: Missing site ID value for object AAA. Object type does not support global objects.

    Exception type: System.Exception
    Stack Trace: 
    at CMS.DataEngine.TranslationReferenceLoader.LoadFromInfoObject(BaseInfo info)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.FileSystemBindingsProcessor.CreateParentElement(XmlNode rootElement, BaseInfo parent)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.FileSystemBindingsProcessor.PrepareNewDocument(String relativePath, BaseInfo parent, String rootElementName)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.CachedFileSystemBindingsProcessor.PrepareNewDocument(String relativePath, BaseInfo parent, String rootElementName)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.FileSystemBindingsProcessor.AppendBindingInternal(BaseInfo binding, String relativePath)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.CachedFileSystemBindingsProcessor.AppendBindingInternal(BaseInfo binding, String relativePath)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreJob.StoreBaseInfo(BaseInfo baseInfo, String relativePath)
    at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractSingleObjectJob.Run(BaseInfo baseInfo)
```

The object AAA is a Product option for the product which set as (global) and used in 2 sites. So these objects were set as global by Kentico admin ui and I do not understand why CI can't deal with them as is?

p.s. I'm super new to the Kentico and really need your help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, place this class (or use the attached file directly)  anywhere into (Old)App_Code folder in your project. The application will restart (upon a codefile change) and the CI should be working correctly.

```
using CMS.Base;
using CMS.Ecommerce; 
using CMS.DataEngine; 
[SystemObjectCustomizationLoader] public partial class CMSModuleLoader {
        /// <summary>
        /// Custom attribute class for the CMSModuleLoader.
        /// </summary>
        private class SystemObjectCustomizationLoaderAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Called automatically when the application starts.
            /// </summary>
            public override void Init()
            {
                // Allows global objects support for product options and variants. Fixes issue with CI serialization of global products with options or global variants having global taxes. 
                SKUInfo.TYPEINFOOPTIONSKU.SupportsGlobalObjects = true;
                SKUInfo.TYPEINFOVARIANT.SupportsGlobalObjects = true;
            }
        } }
```

(с) Zdenek Cetkovsky, E-Commerce Senior Support Specialist

Answer (score 0):

Very last message states:

```
Message: Missing site ID value for object AAA.
```

So try to assing that option to your site(s).

Comment: Hm.. Do I need to create additional set of these objects for the second site? And how it can broke current functionality? *It seems like I cannot do this operation (set the site id) from admin ui, only by using sql.

Comment: Have you added those options through Kentico admin?

Comment: I'm working with an already production live site. So, these objects were already there. And it's working some how as a set of global objects. It's interesting why system can't use them as is, if it is a legal set of objects.

Comment: Kentico does not recommend using CI in production for a couple of reasons

Comment: What the subject we are talking about? I need to make CI working with current set of objects (cos they are absolutely legal for kentico) and I do not understand why it is not. If you have any info which can help to figure it out it'll be nice, but if not just leave it. thanks.

Comment: Ok, the promlem you have is related to the fact that there is no site id specified for tax classes (COM_TaxClass). This is because your Kentico is configured to use global objects (Store Configuration -> Store Settings -> Global objects), so thats why system does not populate site id column in COM_TaxClass table, which means you're right and your object is legal. Not sure why CI fails to process it. Workaround would be to avoid usage of global objects or exclude taxes from CI.

Comment: https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/preparing-your-environment-for-team-development/setting-up-continuous-integration#Settingupcontinuousintegration-Filteringobjecttypes